# Dynamically set current domain in nginx with perl module

Tags: nginx, web-server, perl

I know how to set variables and use subroutines with the nginx builtin perl module INSIDE a "server" directive but, what I need to do is to set/rewrite the current domain before.

Let's say, we have a domain like

```
 admin.foobar.website.com
```

I want that a request to

```
 foobar.othersite.com
```

to point to the first address ( obviously website.com and othersite.com are hosted on the same webserver running nginx :) ).

For reasons I can't explain here, I can not use multiple server_name directive expressions, I have to do this before the server {} block, with perl or anyway possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "before the server {} block"? Before nginx has got a request?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the solution that we have developed for this at http://www.logicwreck.com/index.php/2012/09/11/dynamic-vhosts-for-nginx-with-database-storage-of-domain-and-alias-info/

Comment: you just dinamically change the root ( and i already can accomplish this ), i need to change the domain itself so that nginx handle this transparently as if admin.foobar.website.com was directly requested.

Comment: Actually this is being handled easily by this configuration, you will see the domain requested in the browser with the correct root, and if you access an alias of that domain you'll also the the alias name while the document root will be get from the db mapping.

Comment: ok but i can't this by setting the root, i need to override the Host http header itself OUTSIDE a server directive ... can't explain why, we have a pretty complicated production environment :)

Comment: Then this solution might not work for you

Comment: unfortunately no, thanks anyway, +1 for the effort :)

Comment: I think you need to explain this "complicated environment", rather than what you think you need.  Two answers here satisfy your stated requirements, but you blew them off without a good explanation of why they fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    server_name admin.foobar.website.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass foobar.othersite.com;
    }
}
```